# grid not allowed to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, onclick, grid

I have a grid called "gridbox" and the item "box1" should not be allowed to get clicked a 2nd time. Its for my Tik Tak Toe game.

In the function check(), it should prevent the box from getting clicked a 2nd time.

```
<section class="gridbox">
    <div class="box1" onclick="check()"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Without the rest of your code I don't know exactly how you're storing the state of each cell on the Tic Tac Toe board so I used an array to represent it.

We'll create a variable called `boardState` to represent the X,O state of each cell on the board:

```js
// board state will contain the current state of each cell
// of the tic tac toe board. '','X', 'O', where '' indicates
// an empty cell
//
// This line is basically creating an array of 9 elements (one for each cell)
// and setting each to ''.
var boardState = Array(9).fill('')
```

Your `check` function will look something like this:

```js
// our check function will check whether or not the cell can have the marker placed
function check(target, i) {
    if (boardState[i] === '') { // if the cell is empty
        boardState[i] = currentTurn // update boardState
        target.innerHTML = currentTurn // fill <div> with value

        // switch to other person's turn
        if (currentTurn === 'X') {
            currentTurn = 'O'
        } else {
            currentTurn = 'X'
        }
    }
}
```

This function takes 2 arguments,

- `target`: The element that was clicked
- `i`: The index of the cell that was clicked

Now, when calling the `check` function on your `onclick` event, you can pass the target and index of each, with each div on the board having an increasing index. I've created 3 divs here that show what I'm talking about:

```html
<section class="gridbox">
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 0)"></div>
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 1)"></div>
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 2)"></div>
</section>
```

Now when you click on the div it'll fill in the value only if it's already empty - otherwise, nothing will happen.

Here's the full code to get a basic working example for 3 boxes:

```html
<style>
    div.box1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: solid 1px black;

        /* This part is to center the text */
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>

<script>
    // board state will contain the current state of each cell
    // of the tic tac toe board. '','X', 'O', where '' indicates
    // an empty cell
    //
    // This line is basically creating an array of 9 elements (one for each cell)
    // and setting each to ''.
    var boardState = Array(9).fill('')

    var currentTurn = 'X'

    // our check function will check whether or not the cell can have the marker placed
    function check(target, i) {
        if (boardState[i] === '') { // if the cell is empty
            boardState[i] = currentTurn
            target.innerHTML = currentTurn

            if (currentTurn === 'X') {
                currentTurn = 'O'
            } else {
                currentTurn = 'X'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<section class="gridbox">
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 0)"></div>
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 1)"></div>
    <div class="box1" onclick="check(this, 2)"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's less about whether the box can be clicked but more that nothing should happen if a box is clicked more than once. If you use classes you can check to see if a button has an "active" class (for example), and if it doesn't add an "active" class to it. If the code *does* have an active class nothing happens.

In this example I'm just adding a background colour to a boxes when it's clicked. But you can use this to implement your TTT logic.

```js
// Grab the grid
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

// Attach an event listener to it.
// This allows us to use event delegation to catch
// events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM
grid.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {

  const el = e.target;

  // If it's an element with a box class
  if (el.matches('.box')) {
    
    // If the element doesn't have an active class add one
    // otherwise do nothing
    if (!el.classList.contains('active')) {
      el.classList.add('active');
    }

  }

}
```

```css
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 50px; width: 102px; gap: 2px; }
.box { width: 50px; aspect-ratio: 1; background-color: #efefef; border: 1px solid #666; }
.box:hover:not(.active) { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightblue; }
.active { background-color: lightskyblue; }
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)